# Can not extend disk partition even if the unallocated space is on the left

Tags: windows, windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning

I shrinked my F drive to create unallocated 20 GB volume.

Now I want to extend my F drive back because I don't need it anymore as I have solved the problem for which I initially created it.

I want to extend my F drive but the extend button is greyed or disabled. I think this is caused because disk manager is showing yellow exclamation mark '!' with every drive and saying it is at risk.

Screenshot of disk manager:

[image]

Can you point out the problem and suggest me a solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend booting into a linux based rescue OS from a USB stick and use linux tools to repartition - they tend to be more reliable than windows tools from my experience.

Knoppix is one free example I have used previously: http://www.knopper.net/knoppix/index-en.html

You can then use the included tools fdisk or gparted to repartition drives without loosing ant data on it. Gparted has a graphical interface, supports NTFS and will probably work nicely for you: http://gparted.sourceforge.net

Apparently gparted also provides their very own USB live disk:
http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php

There are many video tutorials on how to setup / use gparted on youtube (e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-sq3PBzplYg)

If you want to use the command-line tool fdisk, it capable of extending partitions and would work something like this:

1) show disk overview with `df -k` and find your drive. It might be called: /dev/sda1 but please make sure you find the right one!

2) `fdisk -cu /dev/sda1` will start the actual partitioning tool, but be aware that this is a very "raw" utility, which rewrites the partitioning table for you.

3) Use `m` to get help and `p` to view the current partitioning layout.

4) You then can delete partitions with `d` followed by the partition number (e.g. `5`) In your case the last partition has already been deleted, but you also need to delete the partition before that and recreate it with a new size (this won't delete contents, just resize the partition).

5) Use `n` for new partition and select `p` for primary.

6) The following default values should do nicely for you. They are the beginning and end of the partition. The default value will be written for you and you can just continue with `enter`.

7) Check the final result with `p` again and finish the whole process with `w`, which will actually write the new partition table to your disk.

Reboot into Windows and all should be fine :)